# Is there a solution/algorithm for a one-directional stable marriage problem?

Tags: optimization, algorithms, constraint-programming

I'm working on an application to assign summer camp kids to activities.  The program input is a list of campers, and a ranked list of each camper's preferred activities.  For example, Alice might rank archery first, then swimming, then hiking.  Bob might rank hiking first, then swimming, then archery.  Activities can only accommodate a certain number of participants, so not every camper will get their first choice.  There are several activity periods, so a camper might get their first choice for one period and second choice for another - choices can't be repeated.

I was hoping to write a stable marriage algorithm for this.  The tricky part is that the preference is only in one direction: campers prefer activities, but activities themselves don't care which campers do them.  Every SM algorithm I've seen (such as Gale-Shapley) assumes that each marriage party has a preference list.  Can the algorithm work if the preferences are only in one direction?

Comment: Of course, since this is a "relaxed" version of the original version, any guarantee of the original version will hold for the relaxed one. You can, for example, assign an arbitrary preference from the activities to the kids, and all the stable marriage guarantees will hold.

Comment: Thanks, Irvan.  I was thinking that, since there are multiple assignment rounds, I could use the existing happiness level of each kid to determine the activity's "preference".  For example, if Alice picks archery first, and archery is full, I would examine Alice's existing assignments and compare them to most-happy kid already in archery.  If Alice is less happy than that kid, I would kick out that kid and assign Alice to archery.  Otherwise, I would not assign Alice to archery.  It seems like this would get more optimal with more rounds, though I can't prove it.

Comment: If you have the "happiness level" for each pair of (kid, activity), and if each activity has a limit on the number of participants, I would use maximum cost matching instead of stable marriage. Maximum cost matching can be used to either maximize the sum of happiness for all kids, or to maximize the minimum happiness for any kid, or both.

Comment: Thanks, Irvan!  The max cost matching articles I found talk about a matrix/graph where each edge is from a unique source to a unique endpoint, like matching workers to jobs in the [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm).  In this program, I want to assign (say) 10 kids to archery, and 5 kids to swimming, according to the max allowed kids per activity and the kids' preference lists.  Would max cost work for that?

Comment: Putting it another way: can I reuse the same activity for more than one kid?  Or should I think of it in terms of N kids and N "slots", where a slot is a space in an activity for a kid?  That would give an NxN matrix, and the Hungarian algorithm would work.  Was that the algorithm you were thinking of?

Comment: One solution is to create multiple copies of each activities (if archery can support 5 people, make 5 entries of archeries). Alternatively, max cost matching can be reduced to a min cost max flow problem. After they are transformed into the min cost max flow graph, there will be a node for each type of activity, and a node for each child. The capacity of the edge connecting an activity node to the sink is equal to the max amount of people that can participate in that activity.

Comment: Thanks very much, Irvan.  I think I will try Munres's algorithm, using a matrix where activites are rows and kids are columns, such that if archery has 5 slots, then there will be 5 archery rows.  I might also try stable marriage.  I'm an amateur, doing this for free, so min cost flow might be more than I can program, but I I'll try it if I can.